# Redirect issue on first login with Stack Exchange OpenID to a Stack Exchange site

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, login, stack-exchange-openid

At my first login to unix.stackexchange.com I noticed the following behaviour:

I came to the [MySQL / swap space full page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17963/mysql-swap-space-full) page from Google. As I noticed this to be a Stack Exchange site, I clicked ‘log in’ to vote up the question. After logging in with Stack Exchange OpenID provider, I got the question: Do you wish to share your information with *unix.stackexchange.com*? I said ‘Confirm’, but then I got redirected to the start page https://unix.stackexchange.com/, not back to the article as, IMHO, it *should* work.

The browser was Firefox 17.0.1.

The workaround is to go back using the browser history (you stay logged in then), but, IMHO, it’s a minor bug anyhow.

Comment: ["I'd like to log in and view this question" "Oh boy! I can help!](http://xkcd.com/869/)

Comment: Do you have such URL? `http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/login?returnurl=%2fquestions%2f17963%2fmysql-swap-space-full` if it's missing the "returnurl" parameter it won't know where to return to.

Comment: The next url from my history looks like that: https://openid.stackexchange.com/account/prompt?session=… There is no returnurl. The issue only happens if you have never came to the site before and have to manually click "confirm" to sign in on open ID. Later on it works normally.

Answer (score 1):

If you leave the site during login the `returnurl` is lost and you'll end up on the "default" page from `/users/login` (which is just `/`).

For the Stack Exchange OpenId, if you use the embedded form you should be fine (just tested it):

[image]
<sub>Visit a page not logged in (the link at the bottom and the top are the same)</sub>

[image]
<sub>Click the Stack Exchange button (some extensions and browser settings break this, vanilla browsers should all work)</sub>

[image]
<sub>Log in</sub>

[image]
<sub>Bam, back on the question page</sub>

---

I also did the same flow with a new account (that requires a first-time confirmation), same behavior but with an extra "please confirm" page after "Sign In".  Forgot to screen grab it.

The TL;DR, if you land on `/users/login` with a `returnurl` set we *do* send you back to the previous page after login.  If you somehow lose `returnurl`, then we send you to the home page by-design.

Comment: So are you saying it's by design that anyone who's logging into a new stackexchange site for the first time should loose their returnurl during the login process? I agree with OP, it feels like a bug. User lands on answer from a new SE site, attempts to vote, prompted to login, logs in, prompted to confirm, confirms, sent to home page.  Then clicks back until he's on the question, still not logged in!